# How to validate json schema of project.json files in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jsonschema, nrwl-nx

in the nx `project.json` files, we have a $schema specification like this.

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json"
}
```

That schema-file exists, but IntelliJ does not validate the file.

How can we configure IntelliJ to use the specified schema for validation?

Note, that we cannot simply use a mapping, because the relative path can be different, depending on the location of the `project.json` file: i.e. it may also be `"/../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest trying

`"$schema": "file://../../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json"`

or `"$schema": "file://node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json"`

so that it is a proper URL where the IDE can fetch from.

Edit: an other approach can be configuring the mapping manually in the IDE, so that you don't rely on the $schema keyword. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `$schema` is generated by nx - so we don't want to change this, as it may lead to problems in the future.